# sql server column value to be converted in comma seperated

Tags: sql, sql-server

Before this question is marked as duplicate, i know how it can be done but without doing a declare statement i want to do it within a query itself

like i have this query

```
select distinct costcenterid,costcentername,costcenterdesc,contactid,expirationdate,portal_id,
    active,customername,branchid,id from costcenter cc
    inner join branchesinportals bp on bp.portalid = cc.portal_id
```

the `branchid` and the `id` fields have different values but all other rows have same values so if i remove those and do a distinct it works good, i get one record

i want that it should always return me one record and combine the columns `branchid` and `id` as a **comma separated values**

i tried looking a this link which seems to be working but how can i integrate that link code with query

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/635166/SQL-Column-Values-as-Comma-Separated-String

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FOR XML` to solve this problem. Here is a list of column names (you can run it in any SQL Server Database):

```
Select Stuff((
    Select ', ' + cast(COLUMN_NAME as varchar(max))
    From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    For XML PATH('')
), 1, 2, '');
```

Here is how to have a one-to-many value set show up:

```
Select Distinct C1.TABLE_NAME,
    Stuff((
        Select ', ' + Cast(COLUMN_NAME as VarChar (Max))
        From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C2
        Where C1.TABLE_NAME = C2.TABLE_NAME
        For Xml Path ('')
    ), 1, 2, '') Columns
From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C1
```

Here is the output from my master database tables and columns:

[image]

Comment: It is wise to select `(... FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.[1]','VARCHAR(MAX)')` to avoid less than (`<`) and greater than (`>`) signs being `&lt;` and `&gt;` in your final string. Not that that is very likely here, but you never know.

Comment: but i want to get it integrated to the query itself, how caan i do that

Comment: For that, we would have to identify unique key column (or combination) in the result set.

Comment: and how we can do that